# Mixing 2 different datatypes preventing code vectorization

Tags: c, sse, vectorization, icc

I have spent many weeks trying to properly hand vectorize a piece of code using Intel SSE intrinsics. But every time I kept encountering the following message (after turning on -vec-report3):

**(line 810) remark: loop was not vectorized: statement cannot be vectorized.**

I finally figured out that this was because I was mixing 2 data-types __m128 (16bytes) and float (4 bytes) (array **v** in code below is a float*).

This meant that since the data types on the left and right hand side are different, it was preventing vectorization.

However I am not sure how to rectify this issue, since for SSE vectorization, I have to load 4 floats at a time into a __m128 variable. Similarly, I face the same issue while storing 4 floats together in Line 818.

```
    #pragma ivdep
    for ( i = 4; i < z - 4; i+=4 )
    {
      it = it2 + i;
      __m128 tmp22 = _mm_loadu_ps(&v[it]);    // Line 810 
      __m128 tmp23 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp22,tmp22);
      __m128 tmp24 = _mm_loadu_ps(&tmp2[i]);
      __m128 tmp25 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp23,tmp24);
      __m128 tmp26 = _mm_loadu_ps(&p2[it]);
      __m128 tmp27 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(tmp25,dt2_i),tmp26);
      __m128 tmp28 = _mm_add_ps(tmp27,tmp26);

      _mm_storeu_ps(&p1[it],_mm_sub_ps(tmp28,_mm_loadu_ps(&p1[it]))); // Line 818
     }
```

Can someone please point me to the correct direction in order to overcome such an issue in resolving mixed datatype conversions to facilitate code vectorization.

Comment: You already vectorized your code. So the compiler can't be vectorize it again. (I suppose it could vectorize SSE to AVX. But that's not happening here.)